# How do I remove one instance of DateTimePicker in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a `DateTimePicker`object according to the value in a `ComboBox`,
but this just show when it is select, then I need to remove this `DateTimePicker`.

```
private void cbxBaseDados_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var dtInical = new DateTimePicker() {
             Name = "dateTimePickerLogInicial",
             Size = new Size(135, 68),
             Margin = new Padding(3, 9, 3, 3)
        };
        var dtFinal = new DateTimePicker() {
            Name = "dateTimePickerLogFinal",
            Size = new Size(135, 68),
            Margin = new Padding(3, 9, 3, 3)
        };
        if (cbxBaseDados.Text.Equals("Value")) {
            lbPeriodo.Hide();
            periodoTimePicker1.Hide();
            periodoTimePicker2.Hide();
            txtPeriodo1.Hide();
            txtPeriodo2.Hide();
            tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 13;
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(dtInical, 6, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(lbAPeriodo, 7, 0);
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(dtFinal, 8, 0);
        } else {
            dtInical.Hide();
            dtFinal.Hide();
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Remove(dtInical);
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Remove(dtFinal);
         }
}
```

Even after `Hide()` and Control `Remove()` the `dtIncial` and `dtFinal` still there.

How should I remove it?

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to create fields within your form , assigned the names " dateTimePickerLogInicial " and " dateTimePickerLogFinal " instead of creating the code itself. Once created the respective fields in the form , call the Hide () method to hide them. This worked for me ...

Answer (score 1):

Before Check Form Already added this control or not

```
      if(tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.ContainsKey("dateTimePickerLogInicial"))
         tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.RemoveByKey("dateTimePickerLogInicial");
       if(tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.ContainsKey("dateTimePickerLogFinal"))
           tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.RemoveByKey("dateTimePickerLogFinal");
            //Your Code Like This
            if (cbxBaseDados.Text.Equals("Value"))
            {
                var dtInical = new DateTimePicker()
                {
                    Name = "dateTimePickerLogInicial",
                    Size = new Size(135, 68),
                    Margin = new Padding(3, 9, 3, 3)
                };
                var dtFinal = new DateTimePicker()
                {
                    Name = "dateTimePickerLogFinal",
                    Size = new Size(135, 68),
                    Margin = new Padding(3, 9, 3, 3)
                };
                lbPeriodo.Hide();
                periodoTimePicker1.Hide();
                periodoTimePicker2.Hide();
                txtPeriodo1.Hide();
                txtPeriodo2.Hide();
                tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 13;
                tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(dtInical, 6, 0);
                tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(lbAPeriodo, 7, 0);
                tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(dtFinal, 8, 0);
            }
```

i hope this use for you

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend creating and deleting a control in the code behind. It is better to create the control on the form like normal and then simply call `Hide()` at the start of the program. Then when you need it you just call `Show()` until you don't need it anymore.

The reason your specific code sample can't hide or delete the control is because the reference you are using is only in the scope of that one method.

Your code is right now creating a new set of controls every time the method is called, and only references to the controls are lost once you leave the scope. This means that you aren't deleting the controls that were created in the previous call, instead you are deleting the new controls you just created.

---

To fix your current code, even though I would recommend you rethink your approach, do the following:

```
DateTimePicker dtInical;
DateTimePicker dtFinal;

private void cbxBaseDados_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (cbxBaseDados.Text.Equals("Value")) {
        if (dtInical == null) {
            dtInical = new DateTimePicker() {
                 Name = "dateTimePickerLogInicial",
                 Size = new Size(135, 68),
                 Margin = new Padding(3, 9, 3, 3)
            };
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(dtInical, 6, 0);
        }
        if (dtFinal == null) {
            dtFinal = new DateTimePicker() {
                Name = "dateTimePickerLogFinal",
                Size = new Size(135, 68),
                Margin = new Padding(3, 9, 3, 3)
            };
            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(dtFinal, 8, 0);
        }
        lbPeriodo.Hide();
        periodoTimePicker1.Hide();
        periodoTimePicker2.Hide();
        txtPeriodo1.Hide();
        txtPeriodo2.Hide();
        tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 13;
        tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(lbAPeriodo, 7, 0);
    } else {
        dtInical.Dispose();
        dtFinal.Dispose();
        dtInical = null;
        dtFinal = null;
    }
}
```

---

I would however, as I said, recommend that you create the controls on the form like normal and simply do this:

```
private void cbxBaseDados_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (cbxBaseDados.Text.Equals("Value")) {
        dtInical.Show();
        dtFinal.Show();
        lbPeriodo.Hide();
        periodoTimePicker1.Hide();
        periodoTimePicker2.Hide();
        txtPeriodo1.Hide();
        txtPeriodo2.Hide();
        tableLayoutPanel2.ColumnCount = 13;
        tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(lbAPeriodo, 7, 0);
    } else {
        dtInical.Hide();
        dtFinal.Hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want to hide it you should try this.

```
dtFinal.Visible = False;
dtInical.Visible = False;
```

Comment: Calling `Hide()` is equal to setting `Visible = false`.